# Mate Panel disappears while using Libreoffice

Tags: libreoffice, mate

When using Libreoffice, if I click on a drop-down button (not the File menu and so on, but for example the text colour palette) and then click somewhere else, the MATE panel will disappear until I run `killall mate-panel`. Is there any way to solve this?

**EDIT:** I have confirmed that this happens for both LibreOffice Writer and Calc with the font/highlighting colour selection button.

**EDIT2:** I have found the problem lies in composition and have submitted an answer to that effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by composition. Disabling it by going to Windows preferences (`Preferences` -> `Windows`) and deselecting `Enable software compositing window manager` solves the problem.